# Should I use Mixed effect repeated measures? Is this the right use case?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I have a data set which has independent variables (metrics) at the weekly level. I have one row of independent variables for every week. The dependent variable is measured at the monthly level. I have the dependent variable value replicated for every week. The questions which I need to answer is:

1. Predict the monthly continuous dependent variable.
2. For every week, which are the metrics(independent variables) that are most
   influential for the dependent variable?

Can I use the mixed effect repeated measures model for this? Or should I build a separate linear regression model for each week and evaluate how the independent variables influence the monthly outcome?

Any suggestion would be really helpful. Apologize if I haven't articulated the problem correctly. Thankful to this community.

Edit: Adding more details:
[image: Example of how the data looks]

So this is how the data looks. For each product the DV value is replicated for those many weeks (and I am aware of the problem now after the below comments..Thank you) since that is only available at the end of the time period after the launch. Also the products are very much comparable. So, its the matter of which metric contributes the best and which metric should I focus on every week as in do I need to run any marketing campaigns or something because one of my metric is down.

Hope this helps?

Comment: After doing a bit of research, I figured this is more of a micro-macro model analysis. Has anyone done any similar analysis using python/R?

Answer (score 0):

The alternative you mention, making alinear model for each week, is essentially the same thing as mixed effects repeated measures. What makes mixed effects special is the random effects associated with each week. In other words, there is some error in your model each week and over time this error has variance.

I highly **recommend against** "replicating" your DV. Instead, drop your inter-weekly measurements and add a 'monthly mean' IV.

Finally, whenever using mixed effects, make sure to test for alternative level-1 error structures.

Comment: Hi Jay- Firstly, thanks for responding. If I drop the inter-weekly measurements then I wont be able to understand the significance of each metric at the weekly level. The insights I am looking for are in week 1 these are the metrics I need to focus on to get to the monthly aggregated number. In week 2 the significant metrics are different etc.

Comment: I understand your issue. It just seems dishonest to 'replicate' your DV like that. If you were interested in weekly relationships, you need weekly data on the DV. I hope you can understand my recommendation. Any conclusions you draw from the 'replication' method you mention will be erroneous.

Comment: I get what you are saying but this is more like a product launch thing. The sales numbers are only available towards the end of  4 weeks when it is launched but all the independent marketing variables are measured before that.

Comment: Are you saying the IVs are measured at different times than the DVs?

Comment: Yes. The IV are more like marketing metrics and DV is the product sales on launch.

Comment: In that case, it seems to me like the marketing metrics are nested in the sales data.

Comment: Jay brings up an important point. The nesting structure of your data is such that weekly marketing scores (your proposed IV) are nested in month. This structure is actually the inverse of what you would like to have if you wanted to construct a multilevel model with marketing predicting your DV monthly sales. I **STRONGLY** urge against replicating your DV as you propose to allow for the use of a multilevel model. It is more than disingenuous as doing so will bias your standard errors.

Comment: In order to provide alternative suggestions I would need to know more about your data. How many observations of monthly data do you have per each unit at that level of the data? How many weekly observations do you have per unit at that level? Do you have specific hypotheses about the role that time plays (in your marketing or your sales data)? For instance, do you expect changes over the 4 weeks in your weekly marketing data and/or do you expect such changes to predict sales in some meaningful way?

Comment: @MattBarstead- I made edits to the original post to show you how the data looks. Yes- there is a marketing mix in the play but also there are some indirect outcomes like google search volume and pre-sales. Please let me know if I am thinking about all this in the right direction.